# remove unnecessary white background from gif with Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I got unnecessary white background with square box while load with **Glide**

Below is my code and screen shot;

```
Glide.with(NearByRestaurantsListActivity.this).load(R.raw.badge_green_yellow).asGif().
   diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).crossFade().into(holder.ivHourlyIcon);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried making the background transparent?

Comment: is it image button?

Comment: @VasudevVyas its a ImageView & I load gif via glide

Comment: try my updated answer may be it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Image Button and apply below code.`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` will help you to white background. load this glide.

```
           <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ivHourlyIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/stillshot"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/circle_gallery"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```